# how to fetch reference property in django template

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using aep on google app engine

```
class Link():
     bag  = db.Referencepropery(Bag) #bag have name, id and other property
     name = db.Stringpropery


object_query = Link.all();
p = paginator( object_query)
object_list = p.page(1);
prefetch_references( object_list.object_list, 'bag')

render_to_response(...,{'object_list':object_list.object_list},...)


#template
{% for object in object_list%}
 {{object.bag.id}} <!--failed to get any value, why???/-->
{% end %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is addressed in a later GAE django framework NON-REL
so going to close this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's several things wrong with your code:

- Your model classes need to extend db.Model
- Your properties need to call the constructor, not just reference it
- A StringProperty isn't a reference, so "prefetch_reference(objectlist, 'name')" doesn't make any sense.

Here's one that makes a bit more sense:

```
class Link(db.Model):
     bag = db.ReferenceProperty(Bag) #bag have name, id and other property
     name = db.StringPropery()

def view():
     objectlist = get_object_list(.....)
     prefetch_reference(objectlist,'name')
```

Comment: I am sorry for quick problem, I did exactly as you do, but I just fail to achieve that

I have detailed my problem